# Why does ListIterator provide an index for elements in a LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

Unlike an ArrayList, a LinkedList can not access an element at a particular point using an index.

If this is the case, then what is the point of the ListIterator providing functionality that returns the index of a particular point in a LinkedList?

Why would I ever need to know the index of a LinkedList, if I can't ever use it to access an element. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You can use `get()` for LinkedList, but it has O(n) time complexity so it can be inefficient in some situations. But you can use element index for estimate order of elements in the list or something else depending of your needs.

Comment: @Zefick You should make that an answer. Also `ListIterator` is not just for `LinkedLists`.

Comment: @Kayaman That's the first time I am hearing this. So I suppose you mean to say that ListIterator can be used for any List type objects.. including ArrayLists ?

Comment: @Grateful The `List` interface defines the `listIterator()` method which unsurprisingly returns a `ListIterator`. `LinkedList` is an odd one out in any case, because there's very few reasons to use it instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Zefick Can you turn your comment into an answer please. I would like to mark this question as being "solved". Thanks.

Comment: Format, descriptive title, language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use get() for LinkedList, but it has O(n) time complexity so it can be inefficient in some situations. But you can use element index for estimate order of elements in the list or something else depending of your needs.